# Facebook running on heroku and Curl Options

Tags: curl, heroku, facebook-apps

I am developing a facebook app running on heroku and i need to change the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` in the `base_facebook.php` file. I can not change the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` value (default set to 10) because heroku fetches the facebook sdk from git.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can just fork the Facebook git and point to that in your submodules in .gitmodules

```
[submodule "sdk"]
    path = sdk
    url = https://github.com/YOUR_USER_NAME/facebook-php-sdk.git
```